# Knockout.js -- understanding foreach and with

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've been going through the learn.knockout.js tutorials and been experimenting.  Can someone explain why this works [*Tutorial: Single page applications, Step 2*] (using `with: chosenFolderData` and `foreach: mails`):

```
<!-- Mails grid -->
<table class="mails" data-bind="with: chosenFolderData">
    <thead><tr><th>From</th><th>To</th><th>Subject</th><th>Date</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: mails">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: from"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: to"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: subject"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: date"></td>
        </tr>     
    </tbody>
</table>
```

but not this (using just `foreach: chosenFolderData.mails`):

```
<!-- Mails grid -->
<table class="mails">
    <thead><tr><th>From</th><th>To</th><th>Subject</th><th>Date</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: chosenFolderData.mails">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: from"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: to"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: subject"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: date"></td>
        </tr>     
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I *suspect* it's because while `chosenFolderData` is observable, `chosenFolderData.mails` is not.  Can anyone tell me for certain?

Many thanks!

-- Ralph

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are not actually accessing the property you want with the way it is written. In the model `chosenFolderData` is an observable and must be called like a method to retrieve the value. To provide the functionality without using `with` (and I suggest not using `with` where high performance is necessary because of the overhead)...

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: chosenFolderData().mails">
```

Comment: @Quintin Robinson - Just so you know, Quintin, I have quoted part of your answer in a question I have just posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927213/performance-tuning-a-knockout-application-guidelines-for-improving-resposne-ti