# Performance tuning a knockout application - guidelines for improving response times

Tags: knockout.js, performance, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a large, complex page that relies heavily on knockout.js. Performance is starting to become an issue but examining the call stack and trying to find the bottlenecks is a real challenge.

I noticed in another question ( [Knockout.js -- understanding foreach and with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916843/knockout-js-understanding-foreach-and-with) ) that the accepted answer has the comment:

> ...and I suggest not using `with` where high performance is necessary
>   because of the overhead...

Assuming the statement is true, this is really useful stuff to know and I have not found a source for such performance tips.

Therefore, my question is:

**Are there general guidelines / top tips that I can apply to help the performance of my application before I get deep into classic performance tuning.**

Comment: I have a number of tips to share, but no time.  Will post tonight.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer - Thanks Ryan. That would be great.

Comment: I don't have any general tips, but you might want to try the beta of 2.1 as the comments suggest there have been some general performance improvements.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think that it would be too much to layout the tips that I have in mind in one answer.

I started a series of blog posts on this topic.  The first post is [here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/03/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha-1ifwith.html).

This post describes a bit how `if/with` work (copies the children as its template and re-renders using the template whenever the binding is triggered) and explains how these bindings can be cause re-renders much more often than expected.

I will update this answer with future posts.

Comment: Excellent blog post, Ryan. Implementing the suggestions around 'if' bindings rerendering has already made a measurable difference to my application. Looking forward to future blog posts on this issue.

Comment: [Here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html) and [here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/06/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha-3-all-bindings.html) are the latest posts on this topic.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the post. I have a question. I'm retrieving an observable array from ajax but the performance is being so slow for load the data on a table. could you recommend me another way ,please?.

Answer (score 6):

One of the biggest gotchas I've found (and not seen discussed elsewhere) is that Knockout *re-evaluates **every** binding on an element whenever **any** binding on the element changes*.

That's ordinarily not a big deal, but for bindings that tend to be expensive (e.g. `template`), it can create significant performance problems.

Attach bindings that render content/children (`template`, `foreach`, etc.) to a virtual element (using the [containerless control flow syntax](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)) if they're not the only binding on the element.

Comment: This jsperf test shows how expensive the indirection of a template binding is.  http://jsperf.com/knockout-template-binding-performance/2

Comment: RP Niemeyer made a blog post concerning this issue: http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/06/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha-3-all-bindings.html

Comment: Knockout 3.0 fixes this problem, incidentally: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/07/09/knockout-v2-3-0-released-v3-0-0-beta-available/

Answer (score 0):

I think mapping can help too you can follow this test and see difference between using jquert map , knockout map  [knockout-map-vs-jquery-map](http://jsperf.com/knockout-map-vs-jquery-map)

When you start using heavily ObservableArrays  mapping become crucial